# laravel without login is sending me to the wrong route

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, bootstrap-4

```
Route::get('/', 'userController@sigIn')->name('sigIn');
Route::post('/login', 'userController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/sigout', 'userController@sigOut')->name('sigOut');
```

I have these routes defined and the rest protected by auth (). when i try to access one of the protections without having created a session, laravel sends me to the login route but should go to sigIn. how do i solve?

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function ()
    {
        Route::get('/home', function () {
            return view('home');
        })->name('home');
```

Comment: that is handled by the `auth` middleware ... open it up and adjust where it is sending them  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Answer (score 0):

In the Authenticate middleware you have to edit this function. and redirect to the route you want.

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

Good luck